# Class 'FloatField' does not define '__truediv__'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-wtforms

When I try to get the values of 'height' & 'weight' variables to use for calculation, I get an error at line 8:

'Class 'FloatField' does not define '**truediv**', so the '/' operator cannot be used on its instances. This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.'

The forms are for storing into a database (Persistence/Shelve) and going to display all the values. I've been able to store and display the 'height, weight and id' variables but I got stuck in the midst of trying to add the 'bmi' variable.

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators, SubmitField, 
FloatField


class AddRecordForm(Form):
    id = StringField('User', [validators.DataRequired()])
    height = FloatField('Height in meters (e.g 1.75)', [validators.Length(min=4, max=4), validators.DataRequired()])
    weight = FloatField('Weight in kilograms', [validators.Length(min=1), validators.DataRequired()])
    bmi = weight/height*height
    submit = SubmitField("Update/Add your Health Information")
```

What I want to do is to use the input values of the variables 'height' & 'weight' for calculation of 'bmi'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it eventually by modifying my Class Record() in another file where I created another data attribute self.__bmi and I managed to get the calculation done inside of the function def get_bmi() instead, so overall what I wanted to display has been done

Record.py

```
class Record:
def __init__(self, height, weight, id):
    self.__height = height
    self.__weight = weight
    self.__id = id
    self.__bmi = (float(weight)/(float(height)*float(height)))

def get_height(self):
    return self.__height

def get_weight(self):
    return self.__weight

def get_id(self):
    return self.__id

def get_bmi(self):
    return self.__bmi
```

summary.html

```
{% extends 'sportshealth.html' %}

{% block header %}
  <h1>{% block title %}Your health statistics!{% endblock %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>These are your health statistics {{ name }}</h1>
<table style="width:50%">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>BMI</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in records %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.get_id() }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.get_height() }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.get_weight() }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.get_bmi() }}</td>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forms provide the highest level API. They contain your field definitions, delegate validation, take input, aggregate errors, and in general function as the glue holding everything together.

For taking input from a form and use it in your application, you need to render the form instance in a template and calculate value in your view function part.

```
from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators, SubmitField,  FloatField


class AddRecordForm(Form):
    id = StringField('User', [validators.DataRequired()])
    height = FloatField('Height in meters (e.g 1.75)', [validators.Length(min=4, max=4), validators.DataRequired()])
    weight = FloatField('Weight in kilograms', [validators.Length(min=1), validators.DataRequired()])

    submit = SubmitField("Update/Add your Health Information")

#Some thing like this must be your View function part

from flask import flash, redirect, url_for, session, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/bmi', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bmi():
    form = AddRecordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        height = form.height.data
        weight = form.weight.data
        bmi = weight/height*height
        #Do database operations here
    for field, errors in AddRecordForm().errors.items(): 
        for error in errors: 
           flash(u"Error in the %s field - %s" % (getattr(form, field).label.text, 'error')) 

    return render_template('bmi.html', form=form)
```

Now in your `bmi.html` template inside `templates` directory render your form as:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
     <p>
        {{ form.id.label }}<br>
        {{ form.id }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.height.label }}<br>
        {{ form.height }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.weight.label }}<br>
        {{ form.weight}}
    </p>

    <p>{{ form.submit }}</p>
</form>
```

Comment: But where does the bmi part come in? Because in my code the '/' operator gives me an error. And for DemoForm(), where is it from?

Comment: When I tried to run the program and go onto the website '/bmi', it gives me this error 'AttributeError: 'AddRecordForm' object has no attribute 'validate_on_submit''

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it eventually by modifying my Class Record() in another file where I created another data attribute self.__bmi and I managed to get the calculation done inside of the function def get_bmi() instead